# Showing a given location on a map in XCode (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, location, uitextfield

I am developing an app that will take in two locations from the user, one of which can be the standard 'current location', the second will be a location of the user's choosing. First of all, I simply want to plot these two locations on a map view.

Can anyone help me take a place name (e.g. Boston MA) from the user via a textfield and get the decimal coordinates as well as dropping a pin on the map?

Answer (score 0):

Read the Location Awareness guide, especially chapter

[UsingGeocoders](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html)

This will deliver a coordinate for given free text.
Further search in the Apple Developper Center for Demo code for that Geocoder.

Further there is a `LocateMe` demo code from Apple, which uses the map (MkMapKit)